# Using Automation to get_Text from Excel. If cell too narrow, get #####. How can I avoid that?

Tags: excel, automation, ole-automation

I'm using Automation to get_Text from an Excel worksheet.  I do this because I need the formatted value (getting the value of the cell doesn't apply any formatting).   If the column the cell is in is too narrow, I get "#####" the same was I would if I were to look at the spreadsheet via Excel. How can I avoid that?

EDIT:

Here is the relevant code:

```
// Return the (string) value of a cell
HRESULT CDialogImport::GetCellValue(IRange *irange, int irow, int icol, CString &cstrValue)
{
// Get dispatch interface for the cell at irow,icol
COleVariant vCell;
HRESULT hr = AutoWrap(
                    DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, 
                    &vCell, 
                    irange, 
                    L"Item", 
                    2,
                    COleVariant((short)(icol+1)), 
                    COleVariant((short)(irow+1)));
if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

// Use the dispatch interface to get the value of the cell
COleVariant result;
hr = AutoWrap(
                DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, 
                &result, 
                vCell.pdispVal, 
                L"Text", 
                0);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
    cstrValue = result; 
    }

return hr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IRange` interface provides an `AutoFit()` method.

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofit(VS.80).aspx), calling this would make columns wide enough to fit their contents. (*It's the .NET interop documentation, but I expect no differences here*)

Be aware that (emphasis mine):

> The expression must be a **row or a range of rows**, or a **column or a range of columns**. Otherwise, this method generates an error.

Comment: Also be aware that if you use the Range.Columns.AutoFit method, the column width may still be adjusting as your code is running. I have the exact same problem and tried using AutoFit but found that there was no way to ensure that the column width had completely and correctly finished adjusting before I started grabbing Range.Text.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get and set the column width (rangeobject.ColumnWidth) - increasing the width before grabbing the text should do the trick.